# Kotlin OkHTTP android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines, networkonmainthread

I am sending http request with kotlin and getting this error

Error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx/xxx.android.ui.xxx}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

**Additional info:** GET request needs to work first. Because the process proceeds according to the response from the URL.

My Code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_MainActivity)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
        if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

    
    }

  
}
```

Comment: Use a different thread or use coroutines.

Comment: I'm very new to kotlin, how can I do this?

Comment: This should give you the idea: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines

Answer (score 3):

Android main components, like `Activities`, `BroadcastReceiver` etc, are running in the **Main Thread**. You can't make a network request (or another potentially long running operation) in the **Main Thread**. You need to schedule it in the background(worker) thread. By using `Call.execute()` method you synchronously send the request. i.e. in the Main Thread.
You can use method `Call.enqueue()` to asynchronously send the request:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback<Response> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<Response>, response: Response<Response>
    ) {
        // handle response
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<ApiResponse>, t: Throwable) {
       // handle error
    }

})
```

There is also another approach of making and handling the request, using **[Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html)**:

```
// suspendCoroutine - suspends a coroutine until request is executed
suspend fun makeRequest(): String = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            continuation.resumeWithException(e) // resume calling coroutine
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            response.use {
                continuation.resume(response.body!!.string()) // resume calling coroutine
            }
        }
    })
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    // ...
    
    lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch { // launching a coroutine
        val result = makeRequest()
        // do something with result
        // save to Preferences
        getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("val001", result).apply(); //save prefences
        println("Request complete")
    }
  
}
```